# ¿Como ordenar una lista de objetos?

Tags: c++, poo, lista

necesito ayuda con esto. Tengo una lista en la que debo almacenar la información de los conductores de taxi, en una de las funciones debo de imprimir un reporte de taxistas que trabajaron horas extras, ordenado de forma descendente. He visto varios ejemplos en internet pero ninguno me ha ayudado, este es el código:

```
void ReporteHorasExtra() {
    for (list<Taxista*>::iterator it = taxistas.begin(); it != taxistas.end(); it++) {
        if ((*it)->horasExtras() > 0) {
            cout << "Nombre:";
            cout<<(*it)->getNombre();
            cout << ' ';
            cout<<(*it)->getApellido();
            cout << ' '<<"Sexo: ";
            if ((*it)->getSexo() == true) {
                cout << "Femenino" << ' ';
            }
            if ((*it)->getSexo() == false) {
                cout << "Masculino" << ' ';
            }
            cout << "Cantidad de horas extra: ";
            cout<<(*it)->horasExtras();
            cout << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Eso es lo que tengo, pero no se como ordenarlos.

**Edición #1**

He actualizado la función de la siguiente forma, quizá esta muy mal y lo siento por eso, pero no he comprendido del todo.

```
void ReporteHorasExtra() {
        for (list<Taxista>::iterator it = taxistas.begin(); it != taxistas.end(); it++) {
            vector<Taxista> horas(taxistas.size());
            copy(taxistas.begin(), taxistas.end(), horas.begin());

            sort(horas.begin(), horas.end(), [](auto &a, auto &b) { return a->horasExtras() > b->horasExtras(); });
            if ((it)->horasExtras() > 0) {
                cout << "Nombre:";
                cout<<(it)->getNombre();
                cout << ' ';
                cout<<(it)->getApellido();
                cout << ' '<<"Sexo: ";
                if ((it)->getSexo() == true) {
                    cout << "Femenino" << ' ';
                }
                if ((it)->getSexo() == false) {
                    cout << "Masculino" << ' ';
                }
                cout << "Cantidad de horas extra: ";
                cout<<(it)->horasExtras();
                cout << endl;
            }
        }

    }
```

Esto es lo que hecho, pero he obtenido [estos](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FfbyP.jpg) errores.

Comment: Basta con preguntarle a [Google](https://www.google.es/search?q=c%2B%2B+ordenar+list).

Comment: @Trauma he buscado pero la verdad no he comprendido del todo como lo puedo hacer

Answer (score 1):

Por lo que puedo ver, tu problema está en la comprensión de código; y es normal porque te estás fijando en los ejemplos más complicados. ¿Y si te dijera que ordenar datos es mucho más fácil de lo que crees?:

```
// Empezamos copiando los taxistas en un vector
std::vector<Taxista*> horas(taxistas.size());
std::copy(taxistas.begin(), taxistas.end(), horas.begin());

// Ordenamos
std::sort(horas.begin(), horas.end(),
          [](auto &a, auto &b){ return a->horasExtras() < b->horasExtras(); });
```

Copiamos los `Taxista*` de tu `list<Taxista*>` en un `vector<Taxista*>` por dos motivos:

1. No queremos alterar la lista original.
2. El algoritmo de ordenación no funciona en listas pero sí funciona en vectores<sup>1</sup>.

El código de ejemplo te deja en `horas` los taxistas ordenados siguiendo según las horas extra que hayan realizado. Para hacer aún más sencillo el código, te aconsejo que sobrecargues el operador de inyección en flujo de datos de salida para `Taxista`:

```
std::ostream <<(std::ostream &o, const Taxista &t)
{
    o << "Nombre: " << t. getNombre() << ' ' << t.getApellido() << ' ';
    o << "Sexo: " << (t.getSexo() ? "Femenino" : "Masculino") << ' ';
    o << "Cantidad de horas extra: " << t.horasExtras() << '\n';

    return o;
}
```

Con estos cambios tu función de reporte de horas extra podría parecerse a:

```
void ReporteHorasExtra() {

    std::vector<Taxista*> horas(taxistas.size());
    std::copy(taxistas.begin(), taxistas.end(), horas.begin());

    std::sort(horas.begin(), horas.end(),
              [](auto &a, auto &b){ return a->horasExtras() < b->horasExtras(); });

    for (const auto &t : horas)
        std::cout << *t << '\n';
}
```

Mucho más fácil de entender, ¿verdad?

---

1. Si quieres saber por qué, te animo a hacer otra pregunta.

Comment: No he comprendido del todo. ¿La sobrecarga hay que realizarla en la clase BaseTaxis o Taxista? Tampoco he comprendido muy bien cómo funciona sort(), es decir lo que le has pasado como parámetro.

Comment: Ni siquiera sabía de la existencia de una clase `BaseTaxis`, así que no: la sobrecarga del operador de inyección a flojo de datos la he hecho asumiendo que sólo existe `Taxista` y debería funcionar con el código que has mostrado.

Comment: Si funciona el código que escribí, pero lo que necesito es que se ordene de forma descendente por las horas extras. La clase BaseTaxis tiene una lista de taxistas así list<Taxista*> taxistas, es en esta clase en donde esta la función ReporteHorasExtra.

Comment: Para ordenar de manera opuesta, sólo debes invertir el comparador que le pasas a `std::sort`, por ejemplo: `b->horasExtras() < a->horasExtras()` o `a->horasExtras > b->horasExtras()`.

Comment: ¿Y como podría hacerlo sin la sobrecarga, o es necesaria?

Comment: ¿Qué sobrecarga? O_o sólo tienes que cambiar el cuerpo de la lambda que le pasas a `std::sort` como tercer argumento: `std::sort(horas.begin(), horas.end(), [](auto &a, auto &b){ return a->horasExtras() > b->horasExtras(); });`

Comment: No se si he comprendido del todo, lo que he hecho ha sido copiar lo que has puesto desde la copia a un vector hasta antes del ciclo for, luego he puesto lo mismo que antes, pero me ha dado varios errores, ¿sabes que he hecho mal? Lo siento pero soy algo nuevo en esto de programación.

Comment: No puedo saber qué has hecho mal sin siquiera saber qué errores has recibido. Posiblemente te esté dando errores de "no se lo que es `std::sort`" o "no se lo que es `std::vector`" lo que significaría que te falta incluir `<vector>` o `<algorithm>`.

Comment: Ya he editado la pregunta con lo que hecho.